# Calculating average depend on number values

Tags: sum, average

Could you please help me with below?

I am trying to calculate average time here `(E)`.
`Column D` specifies how many times this particular name `(A)` exists in database.

If number is 1, average time is calculated: `Qnty (B) * Time (C)`. If number is bigger than 1, it is calculated: `(B1*C1+B2*C2+Bn*Cn)/(B1+B2+Bn)`.

Do you have any ideas?

[image: Table with data]

Answer (score 0):

Write formula for Average Time column

`IF(D1>1,(B1*C1+B2*C2+Bn*Cn)/(B1+B2+Bn), Qnty (B) * Time (C))`